# How to use system function in where SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pass system function `MAX()` in `where` so I tried below code

```
select *  
from tb_sales_entry_total_product 
where Sno = MAX(Sno)
```

but it's showing error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

What's my error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM   Tb_sales_entry_total_product  p1
WHERE  p1.Sno = (SELECT Max(p2.Sno) 
                 FROM  Tb_sales_entry_total_product p2)
```

Comment: @Happy: no, don't be afraid that sql-server needs to get the `Max(Sno)` on every row. The optimizer will execute this query only once since it's not related to the main query.

Comment: @Happy Using Subquery is the apt option for you question. Simple T-SQL are easy for the SQL query optimiser to optimise.

Comment: @Happy you can just put that max value in a variable `declare @maxvalue int = select max(sno) from tb_sales_entry_total product` and use it to filter  the query `select * from tb_sales_entry_total product where sno = @maxvalue` this way you can be sure to get max performance if you still don't trust the engine (in general you can, btw)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *  from tb_sales_entry_total_product p1 
where p1.Sno = (select MAX(p2.Sno) from tb_sales_entry_total_product p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SUB Query`

```
SELECT *  
FROM tb_sales_entry_total_product 
WHERE Sno = (SELECT MAX(Sno) FROM Tb_sales_entry_total_product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query instead ,

```
Select * from tb_sales_entry_total_product 
where Sno = (Select Max(Sno) from tb_sales_entry_total_product )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select * from tb_sales_entry_total_product 
where Sno = (Select Max(Sno) from tb_sales_entry_total_product )
```

## [WORKING SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17948/1)